# How to escape space in folder in JShell /env command in Windows

Tags: java, command-prompt, java-11, jshell

I am trying to set the external classpath in Java 11 JShell using `/env --class-path` command in windows OS. When the folder does not have space, it is working fine as shown below.

[image]

But when the folder is having space, it is giving error as shown below.
[image]

Could you please help how to resolve this error?

EDIT 1: enclosing the path within a single quote or double quote does not work.
[image]

Comment: Try ```--class-path 'C:\Users\siddamis\external jars'``` Please learn to copy and paste from your terminal: Please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.

Comment: @g00se
First of all thanks for taking time out to look at my problem.
Secondly, I have not posted ten or hundred lines of code that you need to copy. It is just a small path that you could even generalize like C:/folder 1/folder 2
Thirdly I have already tried such a solution and it does not work. Please let me know if you have any concrete solution but please make sure you try it yourself first. No on-the-fly solutions, please.
Thanks again

Comment: try forward slashes.  --class-path 'C:/Users/siddamis/external jars

Comment: It won't accept paths with spaces, period. Paths shouldn't have spaces anyway

Comment: try quotes  --class-path 'C:\Users\siddamis\"external ".jar

Comment: @g00se please share valid references to your point, period. Paths can have spaces and it is valid. Paths can't have special symbols like colon (:).

Comment: I wasn't able to get a path with spaces to work, despite quoting it in various ways. And btw, I'm just repeating what *you* said was a problem for you

Comment: @g00se thanks for your efforts in trying to find a solution

Comment: Looks like bug in jshell (does not seem to handle spaces in path on Linux or Windows). Have you checked or submitted to JDK bug database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known issue [JDK-8223941](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8223941) which applies to all OS if there are spaces in the pathnames. Workaround is to use --class-path from the command line, or paths that don't contain spaces.